# How to quickly transform jpg datasets into .pkl for CNN?

Tags: python, image, neural-network, pickle, conv-neural-network

I have a hard time finding the resources for this transformation. I see the input data in some sample code is in .pkl form while the mnist dataset is in .idx3-ubyte. And the formats of dataset used for computing vision vary. I am unfamiliar with none of the formats and would be appreciated if some light can be shed onto this issue. Thank you.

---

update: Now I successfully load my images in .tfrecords format using the code below but as such a format seems unreadable for cnn, I am still trying to modify the code for .pkl format. However, my runs have all failed.

```
            cwd='/Users/Downloads/tflearn_train/'
            classes={'0','1'} #classify into 2 types
            writer= tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter("train.tfrecords") #file to be produced

            for index,name in enumerate(classes):
                class_path=cwd+name+'/'
                for img_name in os.listdir(class_path):
                    if (not img_name.startswith('.') and img_name != 'Thumbs.db'):
                        img_path=class_path+img_name #the path of every pic
                        img=Image.open(img_path,"r")
                        img= img.resize((224,224))
                        img_raw=img.tobytes()#transform pic into binary
                        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                            "label": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[index])),
                            'img_raw': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[img_raw]))
                        }))
                        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
            writer.close()
```

Above works fine. But I tried putting

```
        write_file = open('train.pkl', 'wb')
        cPickle.dump(example, write_file, -1)
        cPickle.dump(example.features.feature['label'].int64_list.value, write_file, -1)
        write_file.close()
```

inside and outside the loop. So far I failed to make a .pkl file that looks like other .pkl file when using cPickle.load

Thanks for every input.

Answer (score 0):

Pickle store information about the structure of the python objects along with the data. For simple tensors, this is probably not necessary.

Instead, the usual way is to dump the matrices data in binary format into a file and reload it straight back into memory. I believe ".idx3-ubyte" as used for MNIST figure dataset is such an example.

If you use python and numpy, you'll be better off using numpy's .npy format which simplifies the process a little bit with the np.load and np.dump functions: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html.

If you need to load a binary data dump, have a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have successfully loaded those images and labels in .tfrecords form but I can not find any code that loads file in such format to train a cnn.

Comment: Assuming tf stands for tensorflow, I have no experience on this, sorry.